# Выделение элемента ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Пытаюсь реализовать выделение элемента в списке. Столкнулся с проблемой, что после зажатия мне нужно выделять элемент который был зажат, но это не происходит. Элемент выделяется только во время следующего нажатия, после удержания. Как мне выделить текущий элемент? И еще вопрос. Можно ли как-то изменить цвет выделения?

вот код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{

ListView main;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    main.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    main.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.names, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    main.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.names, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);

    main.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Системным дефолтным адаптером такое не сделать. Вам нужен кастомный адаптер в котором вам нужно хранить индексы/id данных которые надо выделять и отрисовывать нужное состояние в getView методе адптера

Comment: Можно побольше информации об этом?

Comment: Это слишком долго объяснять, тем более что за годы на эту тему в сети скопилось множество примеров. Вам надо сначала сделать простейший свой адаптер по любому примеру, потом создать в нём список выдененных ID и отображать в getView в зависимости от того есть ли текущий в списке. А потом раз пять всё с нуля переделывать, т.к. ListView устарел, без БД неудобно, БД можно разные и ещё MVP нужен... В общем начинайте этот долгий путь с кастомного адаптера

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно написать свой адаптер для списка. Из-за комментариев код получился большой. Чтобы лучше понимать что происходит, почитайте документацию класса `ArrayAdapter`

Для этого, сначала создаем xml layout в res/layout. Я назвал его `names_list_item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Затем создаем сам адаптер:

```
public class NamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private String[] names;
    private boolean[] selections;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final int colorWhite = Color.WHITE;
    private final int colorGray = Color.GRAY;

    public NamesAdapter(String[] names, Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.names = names;
        this.selections = new boolean[names.length];
    }

    /**
     * Снимает выделение если элемент уже выделен и наоборот
     * @param position
     */
    public void switchSelection(int position){
        selections[position] = !selections[position];
        //оповещаем адаптер об изменениях, чтобы он обновил все элементы списка.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Здесь создаем View и заполняем его данными.
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names_list_item, parent, false);
        boolean isSelected = selections[position];
        String name = names[position];
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(name);

        //Ключевой момент - просто ставим цвет фона в зависимости от значения переменной selection
        if (isSelected){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorGray);
        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorWhite);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * возвращает количество элементов, которые должны быть отображены в нашем списке.
     * если его не переопределить, список останется пустым
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

}
```

А потом передаем этот адаптер нашему списку:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
    private NamesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ListView main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        main.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
        adapter = new NamesAdapter(names, this, R.layout.names_list_item);
        main.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        adapter.switchSelection(position);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А вообще, `ListView` считается немного устаревшим, поэтому постарайтесь как можно быстрее освоить `RecyclerView`, он более гибкий и даёт больше возможностей.

Comment: Отметьте галочкой ответ если он вам помог, чтобы другие тоже увидели решение.